# Add data to Java FX ListView from Map?

Tags: java, listview, dictionary, javafx

I have the following code, and would like to add each "dog" to the ListView. The only way I have found to do this so far is by using an ObservableList, but I have been trying this for a long while and still can't get the hang of it.

Does anyone know how I could display each "dog" from the Map, in a JavaFX Listview?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/abc-guide").get();

    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tbody").first();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
        // Here you can do something with each element
        if (element.text().indexOf("Pelaw Grange") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Shawfield") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Shelbourne Park") > 0
                || element.text().indexOf("Harolds Cross") > 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {

            String dog = element.select("td:eq(0)").text();
            String race = element.select("td:eq(1)").text();
            data.put(dog, race);

        }
```

Comment: You want to add all the keys from the `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add all the keys from the `Map` to your `ListView`. You can do

```
ListView<String> myListView = new ListView<>();

// ...

myListView.getItems().addAll(data.keySet());
```